# heroku rails app domain only working without www

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, dns, controlpanel

I moved an app from my existing ISP to heroku 2 days ago.

It seems like it wasn't working until I realized I had put railslinks.com instead if www.railslinks.com in the heroku web control panel interface.
So when I actually tried http://railslinks.com instead of http://www.railslinks.com it worked

So (today 1 hr ago) I added www.railslinks.com in the heroku control panel.
I made NO changes to my DNS settings with Network Solutions (which show all my various domains with the www prefix).

So far though, I'm not yet able to connect to http://www.railslinks.com

Is there a dns-like delay in getting my heroku change propogated or am I missing something.

Note: 'myapp' is not the actual name, just my placeholder in the document.

DNS Settings at Network Solutions:

[image]

Heroku Settings (I've put both of them there for now, tried www alone didn't help):

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Found it, have to use my "zergio" dns editing tool:**

[image]

Comment: yep, it's working from here now. You don't need to use Zerigo but that's just one of the addons. Also you really don't want to be using the IPs if you can help it, you'd be much better of removing all those A records for the www entries and changing it to a single CNAME entry pointing at <appname>.herokuapp.com

Comment: +1 John that sounds good, however I was just following the Heroku instructions.  They do show what you mention about simple DNS setup here - https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/zerigo_dns but then the Zerigo instructions say this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/zerigo_dns so I did the latter.  What do you think?

Answer (score 2):

Provided you have a CNAME entry for www.myapp.com pointing at either proxy.heroku.com or myappname.herokuapp.coun then it should work.

Adding domains is almost instant on Heroku, this sounds more like a DNS issue but without knowing your real domain makes it tough to diagnose.

Comment: See above for more info via screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

For me this has worked out for [www.reactjs.co](http://www.reactjs.co) (just add www. in the heroku app admin panel):

[herokuapp fix - click here for the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mc0sL.jpg)

Comment: "You need at least 10 reputation to post images." - this is what I get when try to